# Cookie code only works after page refresh

Tags: javascript

I have some code that shows a notice based on a cookie value (=true), and dismisses the notice when a button is clicked (the button, also part of the notice, disappears too). This changes the cookie value to false so the notice is not shown again.

However, I wanted a way to reset the notice by changing the cookie value and refreshing the page. I tried the following, but it only works after a manual refresh of the page. Tested on FireFox. Chrome doesn't let you create cookies locally.

```
<button id="reset_GDPR_notice"><h3>Reset cookie</h3></button>
```

JS

```
document.getElementById('reset_GDPR_notice').addEventListener("click", function(){

  document.cookie = "show_GDPR=true; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT; path=/";
  location.reload(); // refresh page
  //window.location.href = window.location.href;
  //history.go(0);
  //window.location = window.location;

});
```

Comment: You could use `localStorage` instead of a cookie, that would work.

Comment: Good idea, but is it not possible to make the reset cookie idea without the manual page refresh?

Comment: Doesn't that mostly depend on _how you read_ the cookie? I am not sure when the browser resets cookies, but maybe it will only clean them up when the user takes action. But you _do_ know that the cookie has expired as you could read its expiry date yourself, so.... I feel if you read it correctly this shouldnt be an issue regardless.